# Rocket lift off and relative velocities

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rocket-science

Say we had a rocket that was moving in the air at a velocity $100m/s$ (I know this isnt realistic at all but its to keep the maths easy) and the fuel was being ejected at a velocitiy $-10m/s$, negative because its going in opposite direction. I understand that the velocity of rocket is relative to ground, and the fuel velocity relative to the rocket, hence the fuel velocity relative to the ground would be $90m/s$, I think. Now this poses a contradition, is the fuel following the rocket at a velocity of $90m/s$ or is it being sent in the opposite direction at $-10m/s$, I cant tell if the fuel would appear to follow the rocket or not (from an observer on the ground).

Comment: Your calculation is correct (it would follow the rocket), but 10m/s is very slow for a rocket exhaust. It's more likely thousands of metres per second, so in reality going backwards relative to the rocket and the ground.

Comment: So the exhaust velocity is usually greater in magnitude to the rockets velocity

Answer (score 1):

You have correctly calculated the two relative velocities of the fuel, but you still seem a little confused about what relative velocity means.

If you ask "is the fuel going 90 m/s or -10 m/s" the correct answer is the only correct answer is "relative to who?" If you ask "what is the velocity of the fuel relative to the ground?" the answer is "90 m/s" but if you ask "what is the velocity of the fuel relative to the rocket?" the answer is "-10 m/s."

And this is totally okay. **Objects don't have a single true velocity.** The principle of relativity says that there is no such things as absolute velocity, only velocity relative to other objects. When you drive at 60 mph down the highway you aren't going 60 mph, you're going 60 mph *relative to the ground.* You're also going 448,000 mph relative to the Sun, and 0 mph relative to your car. These statements are all equally true and valid.

It may also be helpful to realize that rockets work not because they eject fuel quickly, but because the fuel changes velocity. It's not really important whether the fuel changes velocity from 0 m/s to -10 m/s or from 100 m/s to 90 m/s, the important thing is the difference of -10 m/s. Accelerating the fuel backwards is what pushes the rocket forwards.

For completeness, when rocket engineers talk about fuel speed they basically always are talking about the speed the fuel exits the rocket relative to the rocket.